# Maximum value of $f(x,y)=e^{-y} - \ln x$ on $(x,y) \in (0,1) \times (0,1).$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Let us consider a function $~f(x,y)$ defined by $$f(x,y) = e^{-y} - \ln x,~~ (x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1].$$ Now calculate the minimum and maximum of $f(x,y)$ on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.

My Attempt: For minimum, $~\lim_{y \to 1} e^{-y} = \frac{1}{e}$ and $~\lim_{x \to 1} -\ln x = 0$ and this follows that minimum value of $f(x,y)$ is $\frac{1}{e}.$ Now I am not able to find maximum but the answer is given $2$. Please help me to find this.

Comment: Why does that identify the min?  Shouldn't there be some first and second derivatives somewhere?

Comment: @Randall First and second derivative is not working here, since $d e^{-y} \neq 0$ and $d(\ln x) \neq 0$, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It doesn't have a max or min over the open square.

Comment: @Randall I am sorry sir, It will be closed squares, I have edited.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense:  $\ln(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: @Randall Yes that is the point, I replaced closed squares by open square. The closed squares are given in the book.

Comment: It makes no sense to max/minimize a function over a set that isn't even a valid domain.

Answer (score 1):

The function does not have (absolute) maximum because it is unbounded above (note that $f(x,y)\rightarrow +\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0$).